# .command file that fills a prompt in terminal

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to make a .command file that when executed has a login step. i.e.:

```
macos:~ user$ ssh ...
```

But the above command requires a password input when prompted.

How can you have a .command file that executes the login command, and then inputs the password automatically when promoted.

Comment: Use [key based authentication](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication) for non-interactive SSH.

Comment: Use sshpass utility